# Pseudorandom string shuffle

Tags: string, math, encryption, combinations, shuffle

I'm looking for a way to mix the letters in a string "abcdefghijklmnop" in a unique way using the key(integer).
For example:
Key = 45: "abcdefghijklmnop"->"pppmlkjihgfedcca"
Key = 46: "abcdefghijklmnop"->"ackifgednplhmjob"

The nth permutation method is not suitable because i need the string to look different from the previous / next one(like in hash functions).

Comment: (a) Do you literally mean “a unique way”: Is it necessary that each key within range produces a different result, or is it okay if some keys happen to produce the same result in a “random” way? (b) Your first example repeats letters, your second does not, and you mention permutation, which the first is not. Describe the set of potential results. How many letters does a result have? Is each letter selected independently from the input letters, with repetition allowed? Or are there interactions/correlations/restrictions between the letters in the result, such as not allowing repetitions?

Comment: @EricPostpischil 
a - Yeah, I need every key - string pair to be unique.
b - Repetitions are possible, there are no restrictions, except that the string should always be 16 letters long.
More examples:
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "baaaaaajklaaaaak", "kpnaioeljmcdbfgh".
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Let n be the number of characters in the input and m be the number of characters in the output. A way to select one of the n^m potential output strings from a number, without repetition of outputs is effectively a permutation of the integers from 0 to n^m−1, inclusive. Making it “random” effectively means selection one of the permutations at random. There are n^m! such permutations. Picking a random number from 0 to n^m!−1 may be a bit of a nuisance to compute.

Comment: @EricPostpischi Does this mean that there is no effective method to solve this problem?

Comment: I am not saying that. An ideal solution may be a bit involved, but I am not thinking about it more at the moment, due to lack of time. Somebody else might comment. But another option might be some non-random function that mixes the permutations; some simple one-to-one map from the interval [0, n^m−1] to itself, maybe even a simple linear congruential function.

Comment: @EricPostpischi I found, though not perfect, but a working solution. In short, I edited the MD5 algorithm a bit: I encrypt my integer key and then I get my 'random' string as hash. I still have to test the collision, because I have a string of only 16 chars at the output, which greatly increases its probability.